# Cannot convert type ThreeDCoord to AffectedTile

Tags: c#

I'm using C# To make an emulator. I'm running into a bit of trouble with one of my foreach. Here is the code;

```
            if (Points == null)
            {
                Points = new Dictionary<int, ThreeDCoord>();
            }

            foreach (Rooms.AffectedTile Tile in Points.Values)
            {
               if (!Item.GetRoom().SquareIsOpen(Tile.X, Tile.Y, false))
                    return;
            }
```

The foreach is being under lined red saying 'Cannot convert type ThreeDCoord to AffectedTile'

The definition of ThreeDCoord is this -

```
internal struct ThreeDCoord : IEquatable<ThreeDCoord>
{
    internal int X;
    internal int Y;
    internal int Z;

    internal ThreeDCoord(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
        this.Z = z;
    }

    public bool Equals(ThreeDCoord comparedCoord)
    {
        return (X == comparedCoord.X && Y == comparedCoord.Y && Z ==comparedCoord.Z);
    }

    public bool Equals(Point comparedCoord)
    {
        return (X == comparedCoord.X && Y == comparedCoord.Y);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(ThreeDCoord a, ThreeDCoord b)
    {
        return (a.X == b.X && a.Y == b.Y && a.Z == b.Z);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(ThreeDCoord a, ThreeDCoord b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return X ^ Y ^ Z;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        else
            return base.GetHashCode().Equals(obj.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

This is the definition of AffectedTile -

```
internal class AffectedTile : IEquatable<AffectedTile>
{
    int mX;//byte
    int mY;//byte
    int mI;//byte

    internal AffectedTile(int x, int y, int i)
    {
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
        mI = i;
    }

    internal int X
    {
        get
        {
            return mX;
        }
    }

    internal int Y
    {
        get
        {
            return mY;
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(AffectedTile tile)
    {
        return (this.X == tile.X && this.Y == tile.Y);
    }
}
```

Basically, they are both calculating spots on a pathfinder. Anyone have any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: What (type) is `Points.Values`?

Comment: Yes, both are different types and no implicit conversion exist between them. What is the question?

Comment: Well for a *start*, your `Equals` method is broken in `ThreeDCoord`. You're using hashcodes - don't do that, ever. You've already got a perfectly good `==` overload, so use that.

Comment: Now as for your question - how would you *expect* this to work? You've provided no conversion between the types, so how is the compiler meant to get a value of one type from a value of another?

Comment: @DrKoch it's a local variable. Jon, I'm a bit confused by what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Types not match. AffectedTile must inherit from ThreeDCoord for avoid compile error. 
But better way is rewrite your foreach. You can try something like that:

```
foreach (var threeDCoord in Points.Values)
        {
           if (!Item.GetRoom().SquareIsOpen(threeDCoord.X, threeDCoord.Y, false))
                return;
        }
```

Comment: Not necessarily. It could be implicit or explicit conversion operator also.